# Use PostCSS with react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postcss, class-names, react-select

I am using classNames for styling my component in react, but if i use some components like [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) then how to import styles `react-select/dist/react-select.min.css` and use it inside my component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames/bind';
import styles from './styles.css';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.min.css';
const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

class TestComponent extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <label className={cx('select-label')}>Choose options</label>
          <Select options={[]}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TestComponent;
```

Here is my piece of code, my react-select is not styled. How to achieve that?

Comment: I think, same way as you are using `styles.css` should work.

Comment: Yes!, styles from style.css is working but, react-select style is not.